# How can I reset how Xcode is displaying my project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ide, editor

I was editing a project in Xcode, and went to close it out. So I closed the main window, with the "Run", "choose a device", etc. controls in the bar above the top.

When I closed that window, another popout window appeared from underneath, such as you get by ?double-clicking? a source filename in the editor.

When I reopened the project after restarting Xcode, it opened my project in a semi-popout mode. It has the dimensions and original placement of the popout window. It did display a left pane with which to browse resources, but not the top bar of buttons and controls.

How can I get this project back to displaying the way it normally displays in Xcode? Is there an "editor state" file that I can simply rename?

Either resetting editor behaviour to default, or reverting the display to the last change before I ?saved a state of one popout-style window?, would be welcome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think View->Show Toolbar is what you are looking for.